# Binding nested array in Angular view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am having difficulty binding nested array using ng-Repeat. Is there a way I can bind complex array object to view.

### Scope in directive holds object.

(directive controller is as - controllerAs: **'srCtrl'**)

```
var vm = this;
vm.resultCategories = [[{"id":3,"name":"name3","desc":"2","categoryId":1,"categoryName":"cat 1"},
{"id":1,"name":"name1","desc":"2","categoryId":1,"categoryName":"cat 1"},
{"id":2,"name":"name2","desc":"2","categoryId":1,"categoryName":"cat 1"}],
[{"id":4,"name":"name4","desc":"name1","categoryId":2,"categoryName":"cat 2"},
{"id":2,"name":"name2","desc":"2","categoryId":2,"categoryName":"cat 2"}]];
```

### Binding directive view

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="category in srCtrl.resultCategories">
<h3>{{category.categoryName}}</h3>
</li>
</ul>
```

Any help is appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you only need to list the names in h3 elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to concat all the arrays using a reduce function and a concat function before you serve it up to a ui.  You can either do this through a filter or just within the controller upon receiving the data:

```
vm.resultCategories = vm.resultCategories.reduce(function(last,next){
    return last.concat(next);
})
```

Note there are ways to add nested ng-repeat, but this is not advised for a variety of reasons:

- you are using list items, it would mean you need to create divs to put them together (this could affect your css and overall structure)
- confusing as hell!
- room for potential error

edit:

Another way you achieve this(with less lines) is to use:

```
vm.resultCategories = new Array(vm.resultCategories.join());
```

Note: Although this method is shorter, it actually takes longer to run since the cpu is creating a 'new' array each time.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Concat does solve categoryName display. I have to display name as well beneth categoryName and deep link to description page. Any idea how this can be achived?

Comment: simple, just add a <p>{{category.name}}</p> under your h3 tag